# Iterator on ConcurrentLinkedQueue doesn't iterate to next value

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, queue, java.util.concurrent

I am updating a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` while iterating it. Theoretically, the iterator on this queue should not stop until end of the queue is reached. However, in my program (given below), the iterator stops after the iterating over the initial state (without update) of the queue. What should I do overcome this problem?

```
public static void printTree(Node root) {
    Queue<Node>q=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Node>();
    q.add(root);

    Iterator<Node> iter = q.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        List<Node> childs = iter.next().getChildren();
        for(Node child:childs) {
            q.add(child);
        }
    }

    for (Node item:q) {
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }
}
```

its output is root's value(the one passed into function) and its children's values. it should be showing values of the children of the children but its not. seems like the iterator `iter` only iterates over `root` which is first added into queue and not more.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `childs` is not empty? Can you add this statement to your code `System.out.println(childs.size())` after the line where you say `List<Node> childs = iter.next().getChildren();` and let me know what it prints? Also, according to  the Java Docs for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, there is no guarantee that `iter ` will see the updates made in the while loop.

Comment: @CKing `childs` is not empty. I printed the `size` of `childs` and came out to be `2` i.e children of `root`

Answer (score 1):

In the javadoc of [ConcurrentLinkedQueue#iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#iterator()):

> The returned iterator (...) guarantees to traverse elements as they
>   existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not
>   guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Essentially, when you create a iterator, it will offer a **view over the queue as it is at the moment it is created**. This is one of the reasons why this Collection is thread safe: changing the queue will be done in parallel, i.e. without affecting existing iterators.

**There is no need to use a thread safe collection in this case.** You can use a List, which supports a `ListIterator`. A `ListIterator` is a more powerful `iterator` which supports adding elements:

```
List<Node>q=new LinkedList<Node>();
q.add(root);

ListIterator<Node> iter = q.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    List<Node> childs = iter.next().getChildren();
    for(Node child:childs) {
        iter.add(child);
    }
}

for (Node item:q) {
    System.out.println(item.getValue());
}
```

Here is an alternate implementation of the method, without using iterators, which I would prefer:

```
List<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
q.add(root);

while(!q.isEmpty()) {
  Node node = q.poll();
  q.addAll(node.getChildren());
  System.out.println(node.getValue());
}
```